Lenovo 20e3 computer boots but the UEFI is a total mess. Any Idea on how to fix this one?
I've been playing with a Lenovo 20e3 for a while now, and I ended up breaking the UEFI at some unknown point in the past 8 months or so? To be honest I don't remember what I was doing at that time, but I think I was playing with mint or something...
The computer boot fine, but I can no longer acces the UEFI menu and the output of efibootmgr is now super wierd.
I'd like to fix it a little just so I can finally change the settings in the UEFI again as some of them aren't very friendly to my KDE neon install. This neon istall is curently the only OS on the system, also the computer original came with some customized version of Windows 8.1 if this is of any help.
I don't have access to a recovery disk as Lenovo in pure Lenovo fashion dropped all support for this machine.
Here's the output of efibootmgr:
BootCurrent: 000B
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 000B,0009,000A,0000,0005,0004,0006,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,2ae62a70-411a-4ffe-a482-3fe0b134e174,0x1000,0x96000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0001  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0002  Boot Menu     FvFile(86488440-41bb-42c7-93ac-450fbf7766bf)
Boot0003* CD-ROM:       VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,be9d0102e211f3489efa0b983c96839b)
Boot0004* Internal Storage:     VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,80145304018780439c84491cbd8274fb00)
Boot0005* USB HDD:      VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot0006* USB CD/DVD:   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0007* Network Adapter:      VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0008  System Recovery       FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0009* Ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,f6ac902d-6c24-49eb-a0bc-df0a34141a75,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000A* kali  HD(1,GPT,f72011bf-06e2-4fd1-a42e-2a30cba2f81d,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\kali\grubx64.efi)
Boot000B* KDE neon 6.2  HD(1,GPT,31aa383f-c818-4801-b71a-dcbb044872fa,0x1000,0x96000)/File(\EFI\neon\shimx64.efi)```


I assume you repeatedly hit the required key during POST and still the Laptop does not enter Firmware Settings (BIOS/UEFI). So did you try if Boot Menu can be assessed? The key might be different. Some Lenovo Laptops have a single key that throws a simple menu where you choose what to do based on the Menu items. Any manual available online?

well assuming the user manual is right... it's supposed to be volume up at boot for 5sec and that would make sense since vol down get me in the device list. right now vol up just give me a black screen infinitely

as for the manual it's literally saying the key might be differant depending on the model. but I remember vol up being the right key at some point in the far past. I think the UEFI part is just bricked somehow?

Is it a Laptop or a Tablet without Keyboard? You have mentioned Lenovo-Laptop as one of the tags.

In Lenovo tablets it typically is holding VolumeUp + Power, indeed. In Lenovo laptops OTOH it's F2 (or Fn+F2) or spamming F1 in a few models. Please [edit] and  post the exact model number. And, of note, leterally anything from Windows 8.1 era is  out of support regardless of brand/manufacturer.

the model is in the post already “LENOVO 20e3"  and it is a tablet but it does come with a keyboard that I do not have right now, so I'm using a usb one if I need to. but I remember being able to access UEFI just fine without it in the past.

also the lenovo boot screen have been gone for months (the first one that appears when you turn a computer on)

I suggest you consider adding the correct tag, check if Tablet tag is available and edit accordingly.

ok but I mean that's an x86 computer tbh.

the closest I could find was windows tablet. I edited it accordingly, but I feel like my problem is just UEFI being one of the worst change in computer history.

something esle that might be usefull: the lenovo diangnostic tool couldn't find anything faulty about this computer's hardware except a few bad spots in the digitizer.

UEFI is a type of firmware and different devices may have different ways of accessing Firmware Setup. Going by the initial tag, I thought you are referring to Laptops and hence I gave you some preliminary suggestions. Sorry, that did not know that 20e3 is a tablet. As such I do not know much about tablets. Please wait for others to respond. Regards.

thank you. I appreciate you trying.
